# Chrome extension: contextMenus API is being deprecated - what alternate solution exists that will add the extension to the menu when right clicking?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

since the contextMenus API is being [deprecated](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/contextMenus/) what alternate solution exists if i want my extension to appear in the menu when right clicking? just like in the attached image.

[image]

Comment: It's not deprecated. The documentation server is simply broken. As you can see the warning is about chrome apps, not extensions.

Comment: If I read that I would also be wondering if the api was being deprecated.

Comment: Chromium team apparently thinks that it's okay to serve the broken documentation for more than a month. We can infer from that how much respect they have for extension authors. Even one day would be too much in a project that respects its users/consumers. Chromium team, on the other hand, has been ignoring 100+ bug reports about extensions API for more than five years so I wouldn't be surprised if the documentation will stay broken for at least a year.

Comment: i'm just glad that it's not dead